# Small business DNS with Active Directory

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

We have a small business network that I have never felt is configured right.

- AD Server ip  10.10.1.10  (has a DNS server) named Thatcher
- Router  10.10.1.1 (also has a DNS server)

Router DHCP tells which DNS servers to use I believe it has to tell all clients to use Thatcher as their DNS to resolve locally.

So what should the Thatcher have setup as its DNS Servers to look-up from?  What should the forwarding Servers be from Thatcher?   What should the WAN DNS servers be for the router (google?) ?

I am using the server name to keep the word server to a minimum in this post.   Please let me know what other information you need  and I will edit this post.

Comment: Interesting naming scheme.. Are your other servers named Whitelaw, Soames and Hailsham?

Comment: Chamberlain? Churchill?

Comment: raffles, churchill, jack straw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The router doesn't need to have DNS servers configured unless you have clients that use the router for DNS, which I don't recommend for AD clients.
2. Your AD clients should ONLY use your AD DNS server for DNS.
3. The AD DNS server should use itself for DNS and it doesn't need to use any Forwarders. All Windows DNS servers are configured by default to use the root hint servers in the absence of configured Forwarders and that's how I configure all of my AD DNS servers. This may be open to some debate but IMO if you configure Forwarders on your AD DNS server(s) then you're putting external DNS name resolution for your internal clients at the mercy of the Forwarders, which I prefer not to do.